# using a background image eliminates the text in my element

Tags: html, css

I've a pretty simple background pattern that I'd like to use on my website and every time i set it within an element, whether it be a div or just define it as the body background image it eliminates the text.

Setting a background-color works fine seems to work fine and the text still displays. But as soon as the background is an image the text disappears completely.

Anyone have any idea? Thanks.

Comment: show the code. our psychic abilities are weak

Comment: it's a div element, with a background image selector, and some text contained within it.

Comment: maybe so but we never know how people are attempting to write their code. for all we know you're doing something like `<div background="something.jpg">`

Comment: in that event my background wouldn't be displaying properly. i would be getting a white wall of nothing.

as previously stated my background is displaying properly and eliminating the text contained within its element. i didn't write the markup since i figured it'd be unnecessary to write <div><p>hi</p></div>.

Comment: It's never unnecessary. The whole SO community has very basic expectations. One of which is posting relevant code. I'm not trying to argue, I'm just telling you what we expect. No code is probably why you got downvoted. in your case you should update the question with both your html and css

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic Example of How it should look. Works fine, compare your code with this.

HTML

```
<div class="backgroundImage">
  <h2>This is text</h2>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.backgroundImage {
 background:url('http://placehold.it/200x200') no-repeat;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your question is too broad. Please provide more details.**

Possible reasons behind this (based on my psychic abilities):

- `z-index` is rendering your `imgs` over the text.
- You could be coding the `background-image` property in your `css` improperly.

Here is a proper way to define an image for a background.

#### Fiddle Here: http://jsfiddle.net/uJqG7/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <p>Hello world!</p>
    <h2>Text Works</h2>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    background:url('http://www.hdwallpapers3g.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Images-1.jpg');
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
}
```

Comment: If you feel this helped you resolve the issue, please select it as an 'accepted answer' using the green checkbox at the top left corner of this post.